# Google scripts - issue with string vs cell as function parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm learning Google script as I go along and came across an issue that I could not find a solution for.

I have a function that takes in several several strings and one cell as params.
I assume passing a cell is not same as passing its value (string too btw)

Please find attached code:

```
//return id assigned to data(cell) sheetname
function findInColumn(column, data, colName, sheetname) {

  /*
  data = cell (cell value is 'bag_backpack.png') does not work

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1);
  data = range2.getValue(); (cell value is 'bag_backpack.png')  <---fail too

  data = 'bag_backpack.png';  <---works
  */



  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var column = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column); // like A:A

  var values = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < column.getValues().length; index++) {
    values.push(column.getValues()[index][0])
  }

  var colIndex = getByName(colName, sheetname);
  var rowIndex = values.indexOf(data);
  //grab id value of data
  var range = sheet.getRange(rowIndex+1,colIndex+1);
  var data = range.getValue();

  return data
}
```

While I value and need your feedback I kindly request your bear in mind I'm a novice at best and I've spend several hours searching before asking here.
Thank you for your help.

**Edit**: `bag_backpack.png` is the content of a cell I'm searching in a column to get the row number of said cell.

```
 var rowIndex = values.indexOf(data);
```

Returns the index I need.

However... if I feed a cell to the function instead of a string like a cell elsewhere with `bag_backpack.png` as its content or even derive said value from it:

```
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1);
  data = range2.getValue(); (cell value is 'bag_backpack.png')  <---fail too
```

In said case:

```
     var rowIndex = values.indexOf(data);
```

gives out `-1` instead of index desired.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about your issue? 1. How do you want to use the function? You run it from the script editor or as a custom function? 2. About ``I assume passing a cell is not same as passing its value (string too btw)``, can you explain about this? 3. What is the commented script in your script?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Try and get your code to a bare minimum set that reproduces your problem and state clearly what is the result you' re getting vs what is it that you expect (please edit your question, do **not** address this by replying in the comment's section).

Comment: @HenriqueG.Abreu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for taking the time to reply.

the issue was NOT with the code but with some of the first filename having uppercase in the id,name sheet while the binder sheet it did not.(at least 5 hours on Tent.png/tent.png)

I'm attaching a link to my finished work in hopes it benefits anyone.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jCy1I4r6PeY3kUWrhNno2XO18Jghq6_b1kyN3AflidM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you have doesn't make sense to  me.  I'm guessing that this is what you want.  Since I can't figure out what you want, perhaps you can tell me what I missed.

```
function findInColumn(column,sheetname) {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var rg=sh.getRange(column + ":" + column); /
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var values = [];
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length; i++) {
    values.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return values
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I used the function since it helped me make the code a bit more modular.
But my issue was a typo in the end :'(